# How save file with format ANSI X12 to relation database

Tags: database, database-schema, edi, x12

I need a relational database schema to save the ANSI X12 format. I understand that these data are not suitable for storage in a relational database. If anyone has any scheme or some advice how you can save the file in a relational database, tell me please.

Comment: This is very easy to do with a universal data translator.  You can map the X12 header segments and detail segments or loop segments to your RDBMS.   You can also write your own data parser, but with EDI you should have an audit trail, FA reconciliation, partner management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mapper tool which integrates your ANSI X12 EDI file into a database.
If you want to build your own mapper, you should previously correctly understand the file structure, for each fi